# Can we execute a single task in isolation from a multi task Databricks job

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Can we execute a single task in isolation from a multi-task Databricks job?

Comment: Provide information about what you have tried/attempted to do in order to achieve this requirement? Which single task do you want to execute?

Comment: Do you mean a task inside the workflows? or you mean a spark task?

Comment: Hi @soumya-kole. Did you get any resolution for this? If yes, can you please share the solution

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too

Comment: This functionality is under construction in databricks and will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (unless I misunderstood your question which is not as unlikely).

In order to trigger (*run* or *submit*) a job, you should think of the data to execute this job on. After all, executing a job should have a purpose and in Apache Spark this purpose is data processing.

Data processing in Apache Spark is described using RDD transformations. You should have an RDD first.

The number of tasks is exactly the number of RDD partitions.

And, with all the above said, I'm sure you know what to do to execute a single Spark job regardless of whatever happens in the other parts of your Spark application. You simply have to have a single-partition RDD and, once an action is called, it will trigger a single task with a full isolation from the other tasks.

---

I think I did misunderstand the question since *"multi-task Databricks job"* seems to imply Databricks Jobs (not Spark jobs). I leave the answer till I hear from the OP.

Comment: Thanks Jacek, but I was talking about Databricks job with multiple tasks. A task may be used to process some data. If we have 10 such tasks in a job and we want to process only a couple of datasets only through a couple of tasks, is that possible?